# How to avoid the field changing in Postman?

Tags: javascript, http, axios, request

I'm trying to make HTTP requests to a Netsuite server and I'm using Postman to test them. Then I'm using the JavaScript code generated by Postman in VSCode and it works only the first time. If I want to make another test, I have to send it first from Postman and then copy-paste the code to VSCode again, because some fields of the 'Authorization' parameter change every time a request is sent. Is there a way to avoid this? Or should I do something different in VSCode? These are the parameters I'm using in VSCode:

```
'Authorization':'OAuth realm="",
                 oauth_consumer_key="",
                 oauth_token="",
                 oauth_signature_method="",
                 oauth_timestamp="",
                 oauth_nonce="",
                 oauth_version=""
                 oauth_signature=""',
'Cookie': ''
```

The ones that always change are oauth_timestamp, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature. Here's the complete code:

```
var axios = require('axios');

var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://url',
    headers: {
        'Authorization':'OAuth realm="",
                     oauth_consumer_key="",
                     oauth_token="",
                     oauth_signature_method="",
                     oauth_timestamp="",
                     oauth_nonce="",
                     oauth_version=""
                     oauth_signature=""',
    'Cookie': ''
    }
};

axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: The important value that changes is the nonce. It is used by the server to ensure each request can only be sent once, preventing any sort of replay attack where a third party tries to resend previous requests to gain access. This nonce can typically be any number, but you have to ensure it is unique. One way to do this would be to generate a number based on the time. Here is some more details on nonces: https://www.techtarget.com/searchsecurity/definition/nonce#:~:text=A%20nonce%20is%20a%20random,to%20as%20a%20cryptographic%20nonce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with async function:
something like this:

async function(){

```
            try {
                const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
                let {data} = await axios.get("http://104.248.125.152:1337/api/tasks-category/format",{
                    headers:{
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${userToken}`
                    }
                })
                if (data) {
                    let info = data.data
                    setTasks(info)
                }
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
```